# To which sentence does "Me too" refer?

Tags: meaning

- Hey, Sue! Long time no see.
- Jan? How are you doing?
- Pretty good, thanks. And you?
- Oh, I'm doing OK. I just went to the mall.
- Me too.

To which sentence does "Me too" refer?
Does it mean "I'm doing OK, too" or "I just went to the mall, too"?

Answer (score 3):

Both parties already said how they are doing. One is "pretty good", the other is "doing ok". So it can't be that.

It's clear it refers to going to the mall.

Comment: The immediately preceding statement is the natural supposition. Me: I've joined the Nazi Party, invented a coal-powered space-ship, and had a baby, but I am bored. Someone else: Me too.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's a convoluted example. If I said "I speak English and French" and someone said "me too", I'd safely assume they meant both.